# joining several mp3 files and output as mov file with ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am trying to join several mp3 files and output it as .mov file with ffmpeg.

Anyone knows about the command line to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: http://lyncd.com/2009/02/how-to-merge-mp3-files/

Comment: That's not exactly programming is it, perhaps ask on http://audio.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it with the help of http://www.sourcerally.net/Scripts/20-PHP-MP3-Class

```
<?php
// This is the class to generate mp3 files based on the anti-spam words
// Based on the PHP mp3 class at http://www.sourcerally.net/Scripts/20-PHP-MP3-Class
// Output code based on the FPDF class at http://www.fpdf.org
class Mp3Helper
{
    function convert($fromFile, $toFile)
    {
        exec("ffmpeg -i $fromFile -ab 128k $toFile");
        unlink($fromFile);
    }

    function concatenate($tempFile, $phrases)
    {
        exec("mp3wrap " . $tempFile . " " . $phrases);
    }

    function fix($tempFile, $toFile)
    {
        exec("ffmpeg -y -i " . $tempFile . " -acodec copy " .$toFile);
        unlink($tempFile);
    }   
}
?>


<?php
// This is the class to generate mp3 files based on the anti-spam words
// Based on the PHP mp3 class at http://www.sourcerally.net/Scripts/20-PHP-MP3-Class
// Output code based on the FPDF class at http://www.fpdf.org
class Mp3
{
    var $str;
    var $time;
    var $frames;

    // Create a new mp3
    function mp3($path="")
    {
        if($path!="")
        {
            $this->str = file_get_contents($path);
        }
    }

    // Put an mp3 behind the first mp3
    function mergeBehind($mp3)
    {
        $this->str .= $mp3->str;
    }

    // Calculate where's the end of the sound file
    function getIdvEnd()
    {
        $strlen = strlen($this->str);
        $str = substr($this->str,($strlen-128));
        $str1 = substr($str,0,3);
        if(strtolower($str1) == strtolower('TAG'))
        {
            return $str;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Calculate where's the beginning of the sound file
    function getStart()
    {
        $strlen = strlen($this->str);
        for($i=0;$i<$strlen;$i++)
        {
            $v = substr($this->str,$i,1);
            $value = ord($v);
            if($value == 255)
            {
                return $i;
            }
        }
    }

    // Remove the ID3 tags
    function striptags()
    {
        //Remove start stuff...
        $newStr = '';
        $s = $start = $this->getStart();
        if($s===false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->str = substr($this->str,$start);
        }
        //Remove end tag stuff
        $end = $this->getIdvEnd();
        if($end!==false)
        {
            $this->str = substr($this->str,0,(strlen($this->str)-129));
        }
    }

    // Display an error
    function error($msg)
    {
        //Fatal error
        die('<strong>audio file error: </strong>'.$msg);
    }

    // Send the new mp3 to the browser
    function output($path)
    {
        //Output mp3
        //Send to standard output
        if(ob_get_contents())
        $this->error('Some data has already been output, can\'t send mp3 file');
        if(php_sapi_name()!='cli')
        {
            //We send to a browser
            header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg3');
            if(headers_sent())
            $this->error('Some data has already been output to browser, can\'t send mp3 file');
            header('Content-Length: '.strlen($this->str));
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$path.'"');
        }
        echo $this->str;
        return '';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: can i put an image in the video ?

Comment: Well is not a video, it just concatenate mp3, but with the example executing ffmepg as an exec you can give an idea of how to put it together, :)